# panic: regexp: Compile: error parsing regexp: unexcepted;

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер, golang

Мне нужно спарсить сайт на наличие `IPv4` адресов. Вот сама схема: `(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\‌​d\d?)`.Вот сам адрес - `172.217.20.209:80`, схемы не хотят его парсить. Сколько схем перепробовал не одна не хочет парсить IPv4 адреса!

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>
172.217.20.209:80

</body>
</html>
```

Код парсера:

```
mc := regexp.MustCompile(`(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\‌​d\d?)`) 
match := mc.FindAll(io_body, -1) 
fmt.Println(match)
for _, dss := range match { 
    result = fmt.Sprintf("%s", dss) 
    fmt.Println(result) 
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти все совпадения в тексте, нужно использовать метод [`FindAllString`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString). Кроме того, что количество захватывающих скобок в шаблоне непарно, само регулярное выражение можно улучшить за счёт незахватывающих групп и использования кванитификатора с указанием количества повторений символа (`\d\d?` => `\d{1,2}`).

```
`\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\b`
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/5x0Orc/1).

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?:` - начало незахватываемой группы (которая будет повторена 3 раза)

  - `(?:` - начало незахватываемой группы, в которой определен диапазон блока IP-адреса:

    - `25[0-5]|` - `25`, после которого следует цифра от `0` до `5`
    - `2[0-4]\d|` - `2`, после которого следует цифра от `0` до `4`, а затем одна любая цифра
    - `[01]?` - `0` или `1` (опционально, 1 или 0 раз)
    - `\d{1,2}` - одна или две цифры
  - `)`
  - `\.`
- `){3}` - 3 повтора
- `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})`
- `\b` - граница слова

См. [Go-демо онлайн](https://play.golang.org/p/JGQoe4fW08I):

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    io_body := "<p>My first paragraph.</p>172.217.20.209:80"
    mc := regexp.MustCompile(`\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\b`) 
    match := mc.FindAllString(io_body, -1) 
    fmt.Println(match)
    for _, dss := range match { 
        result := fmt.Sprintf("%s", dss) 
        fmt.Println(result) 
    }
}
```